# input field doesnt work after clear button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hey I want to ask something every time i try to click in clear button it keeps giving me this error and i dont know what the issue is at? and i cant also write in field any more after it clicked.

```
  methods: {
    add () {
      this.tableData.push({
        date: new Date(this.form.date).toDateString(),
        name: this.form.name,
        email: this.form.email
      })
    },
    clear () {
      this.form = ''
    }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XpnC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkbno.png)

Comment: try `this.form.reset()`

Comment: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.form.reset is not a function"
 it shows this error

Comment: Try  `<button type='reset'>Clear</button>` in the main form

Comment: thank you so much for your help ,i really triede none of thoes worked

Comment: the last one worked for you?

Comment: no really it didnt

Comment: share your template or full code that are related to, it seems prop related error.

Comment: i did add photo when ypu look into second one ypu well see code @MdMahamudulHasan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can use any one:

Method 1:

```
clear () {
this.$refs["form"].resetFields();
}
```

Method 2:

```
clear () {
  this.form={
  name="",
  email="",
  desc="",
  date=""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **form** ref to reset the fields.
You need to do something like this -

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- YOUR HTML CODE -->
    <form ref="form">
      <!-- YOUR FORM HTML -->
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script

```
  methods: {
    add () {
      this.tableData.push({
        date: new Date(this.form.date).toDateString(),
        name: this.form.name,
        email: this.form.email
      })
    },
    clear () {
      this.$refs.form.resetFields();
    }
  }
```

Comment: i really did and this one also didnt work

Comment: From the look of the error, it seems that you are receiving "form" prop as a string instead of an object.

Comment: i did add photo up you can see it . so what should i do ,and thanks for you help